# i want to add x seconds to a value for every time is goes past x numOfErrors

Tags: java

I'm bad at math so I'm unsure on how to achieve this: I want `time` to be incremented for 1-3 errors by 3 per error, then 4-6 errors by 5 per error, then 8 per error for 7 or more.

This is what I have done so far, but my problem is I'm unsure how to add 8 seconds on per error for any amount of errors for 7 and above

```
if (numberOfErrors == 1) { time += 3;}
else if (numberOfErrors == 2) {time += 6;}
else if (numberOfErrors == 3) {time += 9;}
else if (numberOfErrors == 4) {time += 14;}
else if (numberOfErrors == 5) {time += 19;}
else if (numberOfErrors == 6) {time += 24;}
else if (numberOfErrors >= 7) {(time += 24) + (numberOfErrors;}
```

What the best approach for this?

Comment: Just wondering, why the specific values and not just increase by 3 for every error?

Comment: I would suggest you use a switch statement rather than if-else statement as if-else statement will be evaluated 1 statement at a time. Besides that, Bohemian has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 else if (numberOfErrors >= 7) {
    time += 24 + (numberOfErrors - 7) * 8;
 }
```

Alternatively, you could do it with less code:

```
time += numberOfErrors * 3;
if (numberOfErrors > 3) {time += (numberOfErrors - 3) * 2;}
if (numberOfErrors > 6) {time += (numberOfErrors - 6) * 3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] errtm = new int[] { 0,3,6,9, 14,19,24};
if (errcnt < 7) time += errtm[errcnt];
else time += 24+8*errcnt;
```

the set we use to increase is a small set, so we can use an array to hold the values.